Question in function used for proof of FToA using fundamental groups
In Hatcher’s Algebraic Topology book, page 31, he gives a proof of FToA and uses this function for the contradiction:
Let the polynomial be $p$. Let $f_r(s) := \frac{p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)}{|p(re^{2\pi is})/p(r)|}$, where $r \geq0$.
I just cannot see why this proof would not work without the dividing by $p(r)$ on both numerator and denominator. In fact, are they not the same function? $f_r(s) = \frac{p(re^{2\pi is})}{|p(re^{2\pi is})|} $. From a proof perspective, this function on the right-hand-side still makes use of the contradicting assumption of $p(z)$ being nonzero everywhere.

Dividing by both does not yield the same as the function you propose, as you are dealing with complex numbers, and so dividing by $p(r)$ can yield a "turn", while dividing in the absolute value of the denominator gives you that the result is still of norm $1$, so that as a function of $s$ you still have a loop of $S^1$ for every value of $r$.
And the reason for dividing in the first place, is to guarantee that $f_r(0)=f_r(1)=1$ for all values of $r$, because you want the homotopy of loops to be relative to the endpoints (you are working with a fundamental group, remember, which means that the loops that interest you are those that start and end at the point you have fixed in your space, which in this case is $S^1,1)$)

So is it correct to say that we divide by $p(r)$ to ensure that we get $1$ instead of $-1$ for $f_r(1)$?

Yeah, that's right, because if the homotopy is relative to the endpoints (the value it takes at $s=0$ and $s=1$), then all $f_r$ represent the same element of the fundamental group of the unit circle based at $1$
